# VS2013 permanent CPU usage even though in idle mode

Tags: visual-studio-2013, cpu-usage

I've recently updated VS2013 to Update 1 and since then VS takes CPU usage to 25% (on a 4 cores intel i5 cpu) permanently even though it's supposed to be idle. I thought it has some unfinished background processes so I left it running for a while but it keeps using the cpu when it's supposed to be idle.

Are you getting a similar behaviour after updating?

**Edit 1**: I'm using git and python tools for vs, so there might be some conflicts after Update 1.

**Edit 2**: The git integration in `VS2013` is buggy. I ran a profiler on `devenv.exe` and `git2-msvstfs.dll` takes most of cpu usage although it should be idle. I sent a failure notice to MS. If you have the same problem please vote for this: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/844616/vs2013-update-1-cpu-usage-not-normal

[image]

**Edit 3**: Update 2 has been recently released. This bug was fixed in VS2013 Update 2.

**Edit 4**: Updates 3 & 4 were released and CPU usage goes crazy due to multiple causes (not only git dll module). Disabling `Browser Link` as in one of the below answers seems to fix the problem.

Answer (score 48, accepted):

**Edit 2**: Possible bug regression in Updates 3 & 4.

**Edit 1**: The bug was fixed in VS2013 Update 2.

One can disable `git` plug-in from `Visual Studio 2013` in this way:

> Tools->Options
>
> Source Control: set **Current source control plug-in** to **None**

Use other `git` clients to manage your repositories.

Comment: I have this same issue using `Visual Studio 2013 Update 2` with ***Current source control plug-in*** set to ***None***

Comment: same here! the problem is related with something else.

Comment: @andresp Can you run a profiler on devenv.exe for a few minutes and see what's using the cpu? (As I did in Edit 2)

Comment: You can find the profiler in Analyze->Profiler and Attach it to another instance of devenv.exe

Comment: I'm running Update 3 and had high CPU usage until I disabled the Git source control plugin; CPU dropped instantly. Possible regression?

Comment: @Thorarin Could be. I haven't updated yet but I gave up using git in VS. There are a lot better tools than the basic git module from VS, e.g. SourceTree from Atlassian.

Comment: Thanks, this fixed the 100% of one core usage by VS2013 update 4 on my Win7 system. Laptop had been screaming at me for weeks.

Comment: This problem happened for me after I installed the 3rd party GIT tools and setting the plugin to None fixed it. Interestingly, after setting this to None, I have set it back to the MS Git provider and the problem has not returned.

Comment: Although this worked for me, it means I have to do without the history and code annotation features. Not good.

Answer (score 199):

For me (VS 2013 update 4) the solution was to disable Browser Link as specified here:

https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T102322

[image]

The CPU slowed down right away from 25 % to 1 %.

Comment: I think this is another bug, unrelated to the git integration bug. As you can see from my screenshot: the CPU load is due to git2-...dll I'm using VS for C/C++ development and the browser link  is not even activated for C/C++ development.

Comment: this worked for me as well - VS2013 + Update 4. Thanks!

Comment: This fixed my issue as well.  Just a guess, i think VS goes haywire due to the Chrome browser spawning up seperate processes for each tab.

Comment: I think what made this issue worse for me was I have my IIS running even after I stop debugging, this fix seems to work.

Comment: Thanks, this solved my few weeks of suffering. CPU was at 40% 30 minutes after I opened one big web solution. Even without doing anything with it. When I unticked the "Enable browser link" option CPU immediately droped to 0%.

Comment: Thanks! Fixed it for me too on Surface Pro 3. It was sitting at 43% cpu utilization when idle. Went to 0% after disabled. Even when running the site on IIS completely and without attaching to process. I suspect it is also interfering with Chrome -> Inspect Element, where you get a massive lag.

Comment: This worked for me as well, but took a restart of each Visual Studio instance that was running to take effect. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks, had same issue and this just works on VS2013 U4.

Comment: woow, that was magically, dropped processor VS processor from 47% to 0.5% and the Computer processing from freezing 100% to 11%

Answer (score 0):

We fixed it by opening the VS in SafeMode. Add / SafeMode to the initiator.

Comment: You shouldn't use VS in SafeMode. Many functionalities are disabled in SafeMode.

Comment: If safemode alleviates the problem you should take a look at the extensions you are running as safemode disables all of them.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was the inclusion of References to the solution that caused the high CPU usage. The project was an IronPython package that also used some DLLs. Adding the DLLs to the References was fine. The first time that a DLL was opened in the Object Browser then CPU hit 25% (1 core) and stayed there. Deleting all the References returned the CPU to normal again.

Yet Another Solution: Delete any objects under the project References.

(VS2013, Update 5, with Python Tools 2.2)

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I normally run several copies of Visual Studio at the same time.  I've found, if I start the 2nd (or 3rd) copy of Visual Studio BEFORE the 1st (or 2nd) copy has completely loaded and settled down, I get a DEVENV stuck at 100% CPU no matter what I do after that.  I have to close all copies, and open again.

I hope this helps someone, it was driving me nuts.

Billy

Answer (score 0):

Had a similar problem with vs2015 - deleting the .suo solution file fixed it for me so far.