# Why does Visual Studio hog all my computer's resources?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I've got a relatively powerful PC (Windows 7 x64, 4 core I7 cpu with 16 GB of RAM), but about every hour it grinds to a halt and I have to restart Visual Studio 2015 which seems to be hogging most of the machine's resources.

It is currently open with my Solution.  I have not debugged the solution for over an hour, but according to the Resource Monitor, Visual Studio is currently:

- Using 100 Threads with an average CPU usage of 35%
- Disk Activity - I can't count how many entries there are for devenv.exe for this PID, but there seems to be one entry for every class in my solution
- Memory - the Private KB is showing at about 2.1 GB

Is this the new Roslyn compile at work?  The memory rises rapidly when I open my solution.  It seems to creep up over time (without me running anything).

Comment: I use it just fine with Update 1 on small solutions (<10 projects, <100 files). On a solution with 100 projects and several thousand files it's unusable. I haven't tracked down whether this is due to Resharper or VS alone, but for this solution I'm staying on 2013 and awaiting VS2015.2 that is out any time now and is supposed to contain lots of perf fixes. You could try the release candidate of 2015.2 to see if the perf has improved: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/news/vs2015-update2-vs.aspx

Comment: try to disable browser link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22785140/vs2013-permanent-cpu-usage-even-though-in-idle-mode

Comment: This is an environmental problem, that always starts by disabling your anti-malware.  If it is Avast then get rid of it asap.  Flaky add-ins are the next candidate.

Comment: Hi Andrew, my solution certainly has several thousand code files, in 30-odd projects.  Also using ReSharper (Ultimate).  Thanks for the info and I'll await update 2 with some eagerness.

Comment: I got access to a different machine and installed VS2015 Update 1.  Things were a lot quicker (though it is an 8-core Xeon machine).  Memory consumption for the same solution was about 1/3 for the devenv.  However, I then installed ReSharper Ultimate to truly compare with my other machine and the memory usage went up significantly.  It may be ReSharper's fault.... Will see how things are after Update 2 is RTW.

Comment: Update 2 was released on the 30-Mar-2016.  I installed this and, with ReSharper Ultimate, memory usage is better when compiling and running tests.  But when debugging...not so great.  Let me know what your findings are Anders (and anyone else).

Comment: Slight caveat to the above.   When I restart Visual Studio and debug, then memory consumption is good.  The amount of free memory however dropped significantly when debugging after the Solution had been left open over-night.  I'll have to monitor this over several days to get a real feel.